# How to make an INSERT with substitution variable and use that variable value on a SUBSTR?

Tags: oracle, insert, oracle-sqldeveloper, substitution, substr

I have this query. What it does is ask me for a value for **&last_name** and **&first_name** and use those values for the SUBSTRs, but it stores the value unless I use the **UNDEFINE *variable*** afterwards.

```
INSERT INTO my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary)
VALUES(3, '&&last_name', '&&first_name', 
LOWER(SUBSTR('&first_name', 1, 1)||SUBSTR('&last_name', 1, 7)), 1100);

UNDEFINE last_name
UNDEFINE first_name;
```

What I want is to make it so it asks me for a value for **last_name** and **first_name** each time I run the query, and to use that value for the SUBSTR concatenation, so I dont have to use the UNDEFINE and can freely reuse the query over and over if I want.

Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove double ampersands; they are used in cases you have the same variable spread throughout your query so that you don't have to enter the same value over and over again.

If you use it once, then there's only one ampersand to be used.

Compare!

```
SQL> select &deptno                                --> 1st
  2  from dept
  3  where deptno = &deptno or &deptno is null;    --> 2nd and 3rd
Enter value for deptno: 10                         --> asked 1st time
old   1: select &deptno
new   1: select 10
Enter value for deptno: 10                         --> asked 2nd time
Enter value for deptno: 10                         --> asked 3rd time
old   3: where deptno = &deptno or &deptno is null
new   3: where deptno = 10 or 10 is null

        10
----------
        10
```

vs.

```
SQL> select &deptno                                --> 1st
  2  from dept
  3  where deptno = &&deptno or &&deptno is null;  --> 2nd and 3rd
Enter value for deptno: 10
old   1: select &&deptno                           --> asked only once
new   1: select 10
old   3: where deptno = &&deptno or &&deptno is null    --> reused here, without asking
new   3: where deptno = 10 or 10 is null

        10
----------
        10

SQL>
```

Once you're done, you do have to `undefine` variable(s), otherwise the same value will be used when you run the query once again.

I don't think that you can do what you want - to be asked only once (which is what `&&` does) without having to `undefine` those variables. A workaround? Switch to a stored procedure which would accept two parameters.

---

**[EDIT]**

Hm, how about declaring a **variable**? Would that help? See an example:

```
SQL> var par_deptno number

SQL> exec :par_deptno := 10;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select :par_deptno, substr(:par_deptno, 1, 1) sub
  2  from dept
  3  where deptno = :par_deptno or :par_deptno is null;

:PAR_DEPTNO S
----------- -
         10 1

SQL>
```

If you'd need another value, you'd again

```
SQL> exec :par_deptno := 30;
```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. What I need is a query that asks me for a value for those variables, specifically for that time running the query.

Comment: For example:


`INSERT INTO my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary)
VALUES(&id, &last_name, &first_name, &userid, &salary);`

In that case it will only ask me once for those values and use those values for that time running the query... So what I want is something that asks me for last_name and first_name values, and that when I give them, they are automatically used for the SUBSTRs.

Comment: (Sorry, went to sleep). I think you got my answer wrong :) OK then, use double ampersands for those variables, i.e. `values (&id, '&&last_name', '&&first_name', &userid, &salary)`. I enclosed them into single quotes which are required for SQL*Plus. If you use a different tool, maybe you won't need them.

Comment: That is not what I need, sorry. I don't think it is possible to do what I want.. I wanted to just use variables with one *&* and to make the query use that value i assigned to them on the SUBSTR. I don't think it is possible because they are temporal variables... Thanks for your time anyways. Sorry for the late answer :(...

Comment: No problem at all. Meanwhile, I added some more code into my answer; have a look, see if it helps.